# Run a CCA eliminating the influence of a third variable

Tags: canonical-correlation

I performed a Canonical Correlation Analysis between two variates, one being clinical traits, and the other one being physiological measures.

This yields significant results, however, it is known that age acts a significant factor on clinical variables.

I would like to know how to get the correlation between the two variates, eliminating the influence the variable age may produce in clinical variate.

Comment: what is cca for you?

Comment: @ttnphns
Canonical correlation analysis

Comment: Are you saying that age is affecting both the clinical traits and the physiological traits and so you want to somehow control for age. Have you considered other procedures other than CCA?

Comment: As I said @Ariel, it affects the clinical variables, which are the one I'm trying to predict. And yes, I could use some other procedure